# Настройка SVN и виртуального хоста под Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache, svn, virtual-hosts

Проблема с настройкой *SVN* и хоста

Репозиторий лежит в `/var/svn/arm` и подтягивается с удаленного

**Настройка хоста:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName svn.example.com

  <Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNPathAuthz off
    SVNPath /var/svn/arm
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Содержимое директории:**

[image: хост]

**Вот что отображается при обращению к хосту:**

[image: хост]

---

Почему пустота, как правильно настроить, что бы отобразилось хоть что-то, а не чистый экран с непонятной надписью?

**Новый конфиг:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName arm.local

    DocumentRoot "/var/svn"

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNPathAuthz off
        SVNParentPath "/var/svn"
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

http://localhost/arm - **Not Found**

http://arm.local/ - **Forbidden**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во-первых, надо включить соответствующий модуль (после чего надо перезапустить `apache`):

```
$ sudo a2enmod dav_svn
```

во-вторых, я думаю, сто́ит указать и `documentroot`. примерно так:

```
...
  ServerName svn.example.com

  documentroot /var/svn

  <Location />
...
```

и я бы порекомендовал изменить `svnpath` на `svnparentpath` (эти директивы нельзя использовать одновременно). тогда можно будет размещать несколько репозиториев в каталоге `/var/svn`:

```
svnparentpath /var/svn
```

Comment: В принципе ничего не изменилось. Убираю директиву "Location" и хост работает нормально, отобразилось содержимое директории. Включаю, и опять то, что на скрине выше.  Модуль включен, что ему еще нужно не знаю

Comment: а что вы ожидаете увидеть? модуль `dav_svn` предоставляет интерфейс к репозиторию(-ям), с которым(-и) должен общаться *svn-клиент*. клиент нормально подключается?

Comment: Я не знаю чего ожидать, я вынужден был использовать SVN, не зная что это такое. Перед этим использовал GIT, значит ожидания те же: "сайт в каком-то состоянии" )

Comment: точно такой же? если вы указали в *docroot-е* и *svnparentpath* пути `/var/svn`, то репозиторий должен быть доступен по ссылке `http://ваш.сервер/arm` и заголовок должен выглядеть примерно как `arm - Revision номер: /`

Comment: на всякий случай проверьте работоспособность репозитория клиентом, как локально на сервере, так и через веб-интерфейс.

Comment: обновил вопрос..

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25853/discussion-between-jilexandr-and-alexander-barakin).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `/var/svn/arm` в том виде, как на скриншоте - не чистый репозиторий, а нормальное дерево репозитория + куча мусора, к репо отношения не имеющая и оттого не показываемая. А **репозиторий** (который физически вовсе *не копия дерева в рабочей копии*) - свежесозданный пустой

> подтягивается с удаленного

вообще не комментирую - я не переводчик и не доктор. Жаргон профессиональный знать надо, а не изобретать свой

**На будущее, с опережением:** крайне не рекомендуется `<Location />` для SVN во избежание массы проблем в процессе - чистый HTTP отдельным деревом и SVN отдельно живет гораздо увереннее (только если у тебя хост не выделен весь полностью под SVN)